# Trouble saving segmented control with core data

Tags: xcode, core-data, uisegmentedcontrol

I thought this issue would be a simple one to over come, but it's providing to be a little harder and frustrating.

I'm using UISegmentedControl to make a selection and then saved to core data with a NSNumber entity. Unfortunately when I try to convert the integer from the segment control into a NSNumber, it comes up (null).
Below is a sample code of my problem.

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Object.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentOutlet;

@property (strong, nonatomic) Object *currentObject;  //core data object with an entity named subObject as an NSNumber

- (IBAction)segmentControlSelected:(id)sender;

@end

//ViewController.m

-(IBAction)segmentControllerSelected
    {
    [self.segmentOutlet selectedSegmentIndex]  // segment control
    currentObject.subObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([self.segmentOutlet selectSegmentIndex]);
NSLog(@"the another Object number is %@", currentObject.subObject);   
    }
```

The NSLog %@ result is (null), so I'm not sure how the correct this.

I've only started to learn programming, so it's probably a basic rookie mistake. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: have you wired your segmentOutlet to the UISegmentedControl in interface builder?

Comment: @TimDean yes, all wired

Comment: Try logging self.segmentOutlet to see what it is set to, then log [self.segmentOutlet selectSegmentIndex]

Comment: Yes, I get the correct number that way, but the problem is saving or converting into an NSNumber for core data. When I do, then it's (null)

Comment: You should also check what currentObject is set to before setting currentObject.subObject. Also, you should be using [NSNumber numberWithInteger] rather than [NSNumber numberWithInt]. I don't think that is causing your problem but it is worth correcting to make sure it doesn't cause other problems.

Comment: I've tried [NSNumber numberwithInteger] as well with the same problem. The currentObject.subObject is an NSNumber, so I've checked that too.Thanks for your suggestions Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `segmentOutlet` needs to be specified as `strong`.  The memory system is discarding it at some point; then, when you try `self.segmentOutlet` the return value is `nil`.  After than invoking `selectSegmentIndex` fails and, by default, returns `nil` and you eventually get to 'null'.  Try:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentOutlet;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the property from weak to strong, and the issue remains. No luck :(

Comment: Then add some debugging code to look at `self` and `self.segmentOutlet` etc.  Or step in the debugger to confirm the values of these.  Something is nil/null at some point. [Starting with CoreData is quite brave!]

Comment: I haven't tried the debugging, so I'll give that a go. Yes, CoreData is not easy, but have been slowly tackling it since I started coding. Hence the thought of wiring segment controls with CoreData would be easier than this

Comment: Solved. I didn't correctly pass the object from the previous view controller. See.....rookie mistake :p Thanks for all your help :)